# $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{-|y-tx|^2} dy = \int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{-|y|^2} dy$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Fix $0\neq t \in \mathbb R,$ Is the following true:
$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{-|y-tx|^2} dy = \int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{-|y|^2} dy.$$
If yes, How to justify it.

Comment: the integral is the same for all x (just do a change of variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lebesgue integral is translation-invariant, so if you do a transformation $y -tx \mapsto y$, you get the same result (and this is true for any $x \in \Bbb R^d$ and $t \in \Bbb R$).